# Bearer token placement in Tweepy 30-day search

Tags: twitter, tweepy, bearer-token

I have obtained my Bearer token using the following on the command line:
`cURL -u 'xxxx:xxxx' --data 'grant_type=client_credentials' 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token'`

...but how do I integrate into my Tweepy code below please? Can't work it out.For now its in the cursor function but it throws an error "Authentication succeeded but account is not authorized to access this resource" :/ TIA

```
import tweepy
import sqlite3

consumer_key = "xxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxxx"
access_token = "xxxx"
access_token_secret = "xxxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

conn = sqlite3.connect('/Users/eeeeee/CODE/RESEARCH/Stewart_SBE/SBE_tweetmine.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tweets_SBE_30day (tweetid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, tweet TEXT, sentiment REAL, tweet_datetime REAL, user_location TEXT,user_followers REAL, user_friends INT, user_favourites INT, user_statuses INT)")
conn.commit()


for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_30_day,environment_name='xxxx', Authorization="Bearer xxxx", q="xxxx", lang="en", tweet_mode="extended").items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text)
    c.execute("INSERT INTO tweets_SBE (tweet_datetime,tweet) VALUES (?, ?)", (tweet.created_at,tweet.full_text))
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Note that `tweet_mode=extended` is not valid in the premium search (all Tweets are returned in full). Also, the query parameter should be `query` and not `q` for 30-day search http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.search_30_day

Comment: I'm not sure how Tweepy handles the keys and tokens, but the Bearer token option explicitly does not use the Access token(s), only consumer key.